# Self-Oscillating Flyback Converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, flyback

I am trying to design a self-oscillating flyback converter using the circuit below as a reference.

[image]

I understand the *ton* time depends upon the values of *Rst*, *Cf*, and *Rf* and the switching mosfet, *M1* switches off when the potential drop across the resistor *Rs* is equal to threshold voltage of the transistor, *Q2*. But I am unable to understand how the values of the resistors and capacitors are calculated and how is *ton* related to *Rst*, *Cf*, and *Rf*.

Comment: You'd better ask the owner of that schematic, and also about two questionable choices: the three series diodes and the resistive divider `Rd1, Rd2`.

Comment: @a concerned citizen - Vout is 1700 V. Diodes are 5A, 800V rated. Some parallel Rs would be in order.

Comment: I am not a fan of these self-relaxing structures as they lack the basic set of protection features like short-circuit and over-voltage protections for instance that these days come for free with cheap PWM controllers. If you want a detailed analysis of this type of circuits, have a look at this [paper](http://www.deltartp.com/dpel/dpelconferencepapers/S19P6.pdf) published by my Delta friends of whom I salute the memory.

Comment: There appears to be a wiring error near U1.  The collector of the transistor running to the secondary side means there is no good reason to be using an opto in here.